# Why alert window not displayed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to popup alert window in my angularjs project.

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mJrkUdMwKoMsun4V573P?p=preview)

Here is button in the view:

```
 <input type="button" ng-click="fireOnExpand()" value="alert"/>
```

Here is function in controller that popup alert window:

```
  $scope.fireOnExpand = function(){
     $window.alert("eee");
  }
```

But when I click on alert button I don't see alert window.

Any idea why popup window not displayed?

Comment: Just use alert('eee');?

Comment: I don't see that code in the live demo you linked to.

Comment: The `$` sign is not needed.

Comment: @Quentin it is linked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to inject the dependency `$window` as follows

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$window) {

   $scope.fireOnExpand = function(){
     $window.alert("eee");
  }
});
```

Here is a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Upwu99PBxdVzDMER0ep3?p=preview)

Alternatively, just use `alert('eee');`

```
$scope.fireOnExpand = function(){
     alert("eee");
  }
```

Here is a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/WyboZKbRyTgdJwDHPBT5?p=preview)

**P.S.**

The main reason your alert window wasn't being displayed after adding `$window`  is, because the button was out of the scope of the `ng-controller`.

Here is the correctly working [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/FqcwAE86pek5dR64PBBI?p=preview)

Comment: Why can't he just use `window.alert` or `alert` rather than `$window`? Saves him from having to add `$window` dependency? -- Never mind, seen your edit :)

Comment: He can!And that's simpler. I wrote that in my comment first, just edited my answer to add that point as well.@Albzi

Comment: There are reasons you use `$window` injected as a dependency in angularjs

Comment: Ah yeah so you did, I didn't realise it was the same person! Sorry!

Comment: @Jamiec, absolutely, the angular docs are a good [point of reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)

Comment: Can you please provide working example on my plunker?